# Semantic UI progress bars not responding on small percentage

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI progress bars:

```
<div class="bars" style="float:left;">
                <div class="ui teal progress" data-percent="" id="example0">
                  <div class="bar"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="ui teal progress" data-percent="" id="example1" style="width:200px;">
                  <div class="bar"></div>
                </div> 
              </div>
```

And assigning a percentage progress with JQuery:

```
 $("#example0").progress(30);
 $("#example0").progress(30);
```

What seems to be the problem is that if the percentage values are too small (around less than 10%) or even when assigning 0% the progress bar appears the same size. Does somebody know why is that so and how it can be fixed?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just how SUI progress bars are, if you look on the docs page you can see [image]

https://semantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html